# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL file at android.content.ContentResolver.delete

Tags: java, android

Getting the above error

```
builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                        if (mImageCaptureUri != null)
                        {
                            //exception at below line
                            getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null,null);
                            mImageCaptureUri = null;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I tried checking if file exists by `new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath()).exists()` it exists but still I'm getting the exception as

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL file:///storage/sdcard0/tmp_avatar_1412858553212.jpg    
at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:984)
```

Comment: Doesn't look like a valid (i.e. system-defined) content URI. What do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried checking if file exists by new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath()).exists() it exists

Note that [there is no requirement that a `Uri` point to a file that you can access](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html).

> still i'm getting the exception as

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL file:///storage/sdcard0/tmp_avatar_1412858553212.jpg at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:984)
```

`ContentResolver` is mostly for `content://` schemes. For a `file://` scheme, you may need to try deleting the file directly yourself.