# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL in android

Tags: android

I am trying to get the image from storage in android

```
 private Bitmap getBitmap() {
            Uri uri = getUri();
            String completePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "CNX/Augmento" + "/" ;
            File file = new File(completePath);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(traverse(file).getAbsolutePath());
            getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
            return bitmap;
        }

public File traverse (File dir) {
        if (dir.exists()) {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                    return file;
                }
            }
        }
        return dir;
    }
```

**I checked in storage Image is present in :** `/storage/emulated/0/CNX/Augmento/IMG_2020_06_18_09_58_41_611.jpg`

**I get the error:**

```
Process: com.cnx.kneurateach, PID: 25439
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL file:///storage/emulated/0/CNX/Augmento/IMG_2020_06_18_09_58_41_611.jpg
        at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1680)
        at com.scanlibrary.ScanFragment.getBitmap(ScanFragment.java:88)
        at com.scanlibrary.ScanFragment.access$200(ScanFragment.java:35)
        at com.scanlibrary.ScanFragment$1.run(ScanFragment.java:75)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL file at android.content.ContentResolver.delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278748/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-unknown-url-file-at-android-content-contentr)

Comment: That does not point to a proper answer ...it is similar though